# Is the Omnimon reference in Season 2 relating to the first Movie?

Tags: digimon

When DNA Digivolve is discovered in Season 2, Izie says that they had seen the evolution happening once before, with Wargraymon and Metalgarurumon DNA Digivolve into Omnimon.

From my understanding, he doesn't make any appearance in the first season and only appears in the first movie.
I'm wondering if Izie is referring to this or if I missed any other Omnimon appearance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is a reference to the first movie. The only other time Omnimon makes an appearance is in Digimon Movie 2 Revenge of Diaboromon where he is defeated and gives his power to Imperialdramon Fighter Mode in order to create Imperialdramon Paladin Mode.